# PHP variable variable name

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I need to use dynamic variable names to create an article template:

```
 $templatesAr = array("intro","paragraphs","image","conclusion","h2");
 $intro = "Intro";
 $paragraphs = "Paragraphs";
 $image = "image.png";
 $conclusion = "Conclusion";
 $h2 = "Heading";

$articletemplateAr = array("h2", "intro", "image",
    "h2", "paragraphs", "h2", "conclusion");`
```

How to echo $article in order from $articletemplateAr:

```
$article = $h2 . $intro . $image . $h2 . $paragraphs . $h2 . $conclusion;
```

Comment: Can't you do foreach($articletemplateAr as $article) or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$article = '';
foreach($articletemplateAr as $item) {
    $article .= $$item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP variable variables are documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). You can use `${$articletemplateAr[$i]}` to access the variable whose name is in the array element.

However, almost any time you find yourself wanting variable variables, a better approach is to use an associative array.

```
$values = array(
    'intro' => "Intro",
    'paragraphs' => "Paragraphs",
    'image' => "image.png",
    'conclusion' => "Conclusion",
    'h2' => "Heading"
);
```

Then you can use `$values[$articletemplateAr[$i]]`.

The reason this is better is because the you can't inadvertently access unintended variables, you're limited to the elements in the array. This is especially important if the elements of `$articletemplateAr` come from an external source.

Comment: Got my vote because this is cleaner than variable variables. An allows you to insure that you're actually using the intended key/value.